# Google API Java OCR

Tags: google-api, ocr

I'm wondering if it is poosible to upload and OCR a document using google-docs api in  Java. I know I can in a way perform this by making such a http post:

```
POST /feeds/default/private/full?ocr=true HTTP/1.1
Host: docs.google.com
GData-Version: 3.0
Authorization: 
Content-Length: 1984
Content-Type: image/png
Slug: OCRd Doc

... png contents here ...
```

But is it possible to achieve this using DocsService?

Comment: Ok that was real easy. For those interested: 
You just have to add `myService.insert(new URL(
    "http://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full?ocr=true"),
    newDocument);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add:

```
myService.insert(new URL( "http://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full?ocr=true"), newDocument);
```